# MySQL Cli show current db-name all the time

Tags: mysql, mariadb

- MariaDB Cli can show dbName all the time , default is `MySQL [(none)]>`
- I know MySQL can use `select database();` or `status;` to show dbName
- Can MysQL do as MariaDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html:

> The `prompt` command reconfigures the default mysql> prompt.

The documentation shows you how to use the `prompt` command to set several types of metacharacters in the prompt. You configure it to run every time the mysql client starts.